# Gradle 7.3.3 / Plugin 7.2.1 does not include native debug symbols in bundles

Tags: android, debugging, symbols

It was the same with Gradle 7.0.3 plugin 7.0.2 with Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 3.

Now with Android Studio 2021.2.1 Patch 1, gradle 7.3.3 plugin 7.2.1, still no debug symbols in app bundles.

If I revert to gradle 4.3.1 plugin 6.5.1, everything is working again.

Noticeably lib folder is also 4 times bigger with latest gradle than it was before!

The gradle builds are not changed in any ways between version of gradle's. One version works (6.5.1), the other does not (7.2.1).

See attached screenshot showing app bundles with plugin 7.2.1 on the left, 6.5.1 on the right.

The left one has no debug symbols included and lib folder is 2.8MB, the one on the right have debug symbols and lib folder is 714KB!

Any help would be much appreciated as it's been 6 months (if not a couple of years at it started after release 6.5.1) I've reported this to Google and received no reply or help whatsoever except 'the debug symbols are generated'. Note that they never said symbols are included in bundles.

Comment: hey @3c71, did you ever find a way to make this work? besides reverting WAY back to an old gradle?  thx

Comment: @eric, yes kind'of. I've added an answer for this, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Generating NDK debug symbols in bundles is very messy no matter what version of Android Studio, gradle, gradle plugin and NDK you use.

Turns out there are many incompatibilities between versions, and each version of Android Studio requires specific versions of gradle/plugin/ndk to successfully generate debug symbols in bundles.

After opening many bug reports with Google, it turns out that specifying ndk version manually is a very bad idea in the first place and will often cause the issue.

If you check comment #7 and #8, it offers some insight into this issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/234737605

As of now I'm using those versions (without specifying NDK version):

- Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1
- Gradle Plugin 7.3.1
- Gradle 7.4